# How to preallocate a datetime array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, datetime

I would like to know if there is a way to pre-allocate a `datetime` array in Matlab.

I explain my problem: I need to read several dates (let suppose they are 10) from many files (let say they are 100) and I would like to store it in a datetime array 10X100. 
If my data was simple numeric date (ie `double`) I can pre-allocate an array as: `DataTable = zeros(10,100)`. I would like to do something similar with `datetime` data type but I was not able to find how, can you help me?

**Possible workaround/solution found**

I made some tests and I found this workaround to mayproblem:

```
DataTable = repmat(datetime(0,0,0), 10, 100);
```

This way I have from the beginning an array 10X100 of the type `datetime` initialized to a default value. I posted this edit to the question in case it can be helpful for someone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit (better solution):**

Another option I discovered recently is using the `NaT()` function that was introduced in R2015b (which @csanchisb also mentioned in his answer).  `NaT` stands for "not a time", similar to `NaN` for floating point values.  This is probably the best solution since it uses a built-in function that can do exactly what you want, and also makes it clear which entries of the matrix have not been set to valid datetime values.

```
DataTable = NaT(10,100);
```

After running the above line of code, you can loop through and overwrite each entry in `DataTable` with the actual `datetime` objects as you read them in.

**Original answer:**

I think the solution posted by the author using `repmat()` is probably best in most cases, but here is another possible solution:

```
DataTable = datetime(zeros(10,100), zeros(10,100), zeros(10,100));
```

or

```
DataTable = zeros(10,100);
DataTable = datetime(DataTable, DataTable, DataTable);
```

I wrote some quick code to compare the performance of this with the author's `repmat()` method.  It looks like this method is a little faster for small arrays (~100 datetime objects), but `repmat()` is quite a bit faster for large arrays (~1 million datetime objects).

However, since pre-allocation usually only happens once, the speed probably doesn't matter nearly as much as how semantically clear the code is.  In this case, I'd still go with the `repmat()` solution since I think it's easier to interpret what its code is doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize an empty one:

```
DataTable = datetime([],[],[]);
```

and then find some smart way to fill it. This means that you can add elements dynamically depending on your algorhitm needs.

Are you sure it makes sense to have a fixed array with all zeros?

Comment: Thanks @sparaflAsh using your solution I initially have `DataTable` as a 1X1 datetime. I know that then I can add elements dynamically but I was wondering if I can create from scratch  `DataTable`  with the final dimensions.

Comment: Well. I don't have Matlab on this machine, but I suppose you can play with the arithmetic of datetime.

[Here for details](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compute-elapsed-time.html)

This example might help you:

_Add a number of calendar days to t1_

`t1 = datetime('now');
t3 = t1 + caldays(0:2)
t3 = 

   08-Mar-2014 00:00:00   09-Mar-2014 00:00:00   10-Mar-2014 00:00:00`

Answer (score 3):

`datetime(0, 0, 0)` will produce `30-Nov--0001`, which is as good a default as any. The obvious way to build the array would be `repmat(datetime(0, 0, 0), 10, 100)`.

An alternative would be to use `NaT` ('not a time'), which is of type `datetime` and is more obviously a default value. In that case, you can initialize the array directly with `NaT(10, 100)`.

Comment: +1 for the `NaT` version, very elegant! On my machine, this is about twice as fast compared to `repmat(datetime(0, 0, 0), 10, 100)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "cell Array" like this:

```
DataTable = cell(10,100);
```

and fill each cell using Braces.

**for example:** `DataTable{2,3}='2015-12-2';`

Comment: You are right but in this case I have a cell and I lost the `datetime` datatype