# MATLAB - concatenating a datetime array to an empty array

Tags: arrays, matlab, datetime

I have a project which outputs data into many files. These files look something like this as interpreted by `readmatrix`:

```
ans =

  8×8 table

         Date_Time         EZOO2Con___    EZOCO2Con_ppm_    SGPCO2Con_ppm_    SGPTVOC_ppb_    BMEHumidity___    BMEPressure_Pa_    BMETemp_DegC_
    ___________________    ___________    ______________    ______________    ____________    ______________    _______________    _____________

    09/06/2022 11:55:17       19.16            419               400               0               48.5              95948             22.57    
    09/06/2022 11:55:18       19.16            419               400               0              48.89              99577             22.58    
    09/06/2022 11:55:19       19.16            419               400               0              48.89              99578             22.58    
    09/06/2022 11:55:20       19.15            420               400               0              48.84              99584             22.57    
    09/06/2022 11:55:21       19.15            420               400               0              48.95              99574             22.58    
    09/06/2022 11:55:22       19.15            421               400               0              49.15              99578             22.57    
    09/06/2022 11:55:23       19.15            421               400               0               48.9              99577             22.56    
    09/06/2022 11:55:24       19.15            422               400               0               48.9              99573             22.57
```

For my previous test, I have approx. 289 separate files of this format which I'd like to combine together in 8 arrays for plotting.

The Date_Time column is a string with MM/DD/YYYY and HH:MM:SS separated by a space. When using the table2array command, I am able to convert the date&time column of each file's data into a datetime array. However, I am unable to use the `cat` or `vertcat` functions to append the date&time column to my "combined" array. Below is the code that's giving me trouble:

```
for k = 1:length(fileList)
    baseFileName = fileList(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(fileList(k).folder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    data = readtable(fullFileName);
    timecol = data(:,1);
    EZOCO2col = data(:,2);
    EZOO2col = data(:, 3);
    SGP30CO2col = data(:, 4);
    SGP30TVOCcol = data(:, 5);
    BME280Humcol = data(:, 6);
    BME280Presscol = data(:, 7);
    BME280Tempcol = data(:, 8);
    
    timecol_array = table2array(timecol);
    EZOCO2col_array = table2array(EZOCO2col);
    EZOO2col_array = table2array(EZOO2col);
    SGP30CO2col_array = table2array(SGP30CO2col);
    SGP30TVOCcol_array = table2array(SGP30TVOCcol);
    BME280Humcol_array = table2array(BME280Humcol);
    BME280Presscol_array = table2array(BME280Presscol);
    BME280Tempcol_array = table2array(BME280Tempcol);
    
    timecol_tot  = cat(1, timecol_tot, timecol_array);
    EZOCO2col_tot = cat(1, EZOCO2col_tot, EZOCO2col_array);
    EZOO2col_tot = cat(1, EZOO2col_tot, EZOO2col_array);
    SGP30CO2col_tot = cat(1, SGP30CO2col_tot, SGP30CO2col_array);
    SGP30TVOCcol_tot = cat(1, SGP30TVOCcol_tot, SGP30TVOCcol_array);
    BME280Humcol_tot = cat(1, BME280Humcol_tot, BME280Humcol_array);
    BME280Presscol_tot = cat(1, BME280Presscol_tot, BME280Presscol_array);
    BME280Tempcol_tot = cat(1, BME280Tempcol_tot, BME280Tempcol_array);

    
end
```

I receive this error each time:

```
Error using datetime/cat (line 1376)
All inputs must be datetimes or date/time character vectors or date/time strings.

Error in Plot_attempt_9_6_22_1 (line 66)
    timecol_tot  = cat(1, timecol_tot, timecol_array);
```

As per [How to preallocate a datetime array in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041009/how-to-preallocate-a-datetime-array-in-matlab), I have tried:

`timecol_tot = [];`,
`timecol_tot = datetime([],[],[],[],[],[]);`, and
`timecol_tot = NaT(1,1);` to no avail.

Because the length of each of these files may vary, I didn't try pre-allocating the datetime array in the size of the incoming data, since that may not work across different datasets. However, it *does* work if I have only *one* file.

Is there a way to do this that would allow me to just initialize an empty array and concatenate `datetime` arrays to it *without* defining the size of the first `datetime` set to add?

Comment: Why not simply concatenate all the tables that you get out of `readtable`?

Comment: Also, note that you can use `{}` indexing with tables to get the values out directly, without the need for `table2array`. I.e. `data{:,1}` will get you the `datetime`s.

Comment: Hi @Edric, thanks for the comments. I'll try eliminating the table2array commands to cut down on the length of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this problem by adding an `if` statement, and now, it looks something like this:

```
if k == 1
    timecol_tot  = timecol_array;
    EZOCO2col_tot = cat(1, EZOCO2col_tot, EZOCO2col_double);
    EZOO2col_tot = cat(1, EZOO2col_tot, EZOO2col_double);
    SGP30CO2col_tot = cat(1, SGP30CO2col_tot, SGP30CO2col_array);
    SGP30TVOCcol_tot = cat(1, SGP30TVOCcol_tot, SGP30TVOCcol_array);
    BME280Humcol_tot = cat(1, BME280Humcol_tot, BME280Humcol_array);
    BME280Presscol_tot = cat(1, BME280Presscol_tot, BME280Presscol_array);
    BME280Tempcol_tot = cat(1, BME280Tempcol_tot, BME280Tempcol_array);
else
    timecol_tot  = cat(1, timecol_tot, timecol_array);
    EZOCO2col_tot = cat(1, EZOCO2col_tot, EZOCO2col_double);
    EZOO2col_tot = cat(1, EZOO2col_tot, EZOO2col_double);
    SGP30CO2col_tot = cat(1, SGP30CO2col_tot, SGP30CO2col_array);
    SGP30TVOCcol_tot = cat(1, SGP30TVOCcol_tot, SGP30TVOCcol_array);
    BME280Humcol_tot = cat(1, BME280Humcol_tot, BME280Humcol_array);
    BME280Presscol_tot = cat(1, BME280Presscol_tot, BME280Presscol_array);
    BME280Tempcol_tot = cat(1, BME280Tempcol_tot, BME280Tempcol_array);
end
```

Another reason that I was getting a type error was because *some of my files were empty or corrupted.* If you're having similar issues, check to make sure that you're not working with empty or corrupted csv's!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking 2 questions, I am new here but some moderators may tell you break it down into 2 separate questions.

I am here answering both anyway :

1. The error doesn't seem to be coming from `cat`

With the data you have provided I have reproduced cat output and cat works fine; it concatenates `DATATIME` when required and floats told to.

The problem has to be somewhere else ; as long as you feed `cat` with same format there shouldn't be any error.

The error comes from a function called `Plot_attempt_9_6_22_1` right?

Either

- you are sending to `plot` rows instead of columns therefore `plot` input vectors contain mixed formats, a transpose or more than one missing somewhere,

or

- somewhere your are mixing date/time formats with something that is not date/time type.

2.- Do you really need to preallocate memory?

In any case MATLAB suggests to preallocate tables with the following expression :

```
T = table('Size',sz,'VariableTypes',varTypes)
```

not with the C/C++ style mentioned in question

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Eventually I settled on an `if` statement, where in the first iteration of the `for` loop I assign the value of timecol_array to timecol_tot, and it works from there. Then, I found that some of my files were empty for some reason, and that was also causing a type issue since empty cells don't get imported as `datetime`.